# Deploying web application in SUP2.0

Tags: sup

I have deployed my web application in the folder 
C:\Sybase\UnwiredPlatform\Servers\UnwiredServer\deploy\webapps 
of SUP server. I have stoped and restarted the server. But it is not working.

i have also checked the server error log file it is not showing any error.

I have tested the same in tomcat server 6.0 it is working fine.

I am new in SUP2.0 environment. Please help me in deploying web application also let me know if i am following the right procedure..

thanks in advance

Pratap Kumar Panda

Answer (score 0):

The suggested way to deploy a webapp is though Eclipse. (with the sybase plugin installed)

See these series of tutorials

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ls-swn433g0